# How do I decide whether a method-function pointer belongs in the instance structure or class structure in GObject?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gstreamer, glib, gobject

in glib GObject for example:

```
typedef struct _MyInstance MyInstance;
struct _MyInstance {
        GObject parent;
        ......//instance variable
        ......//this place is method function pointer in instance structure.      
};

typedef struct _MyInstanceClass MyInstanceClass;
struct _MyInstanceClass {
        GObjectClass parent_class;
       ......//class variable
       ......//this place is method function pointer in class structure.
};
```

I don't understand that the method function pointer puts in class or instance structure that it seen to same . what difference are they? I think that class function method pointers each of instance object is used to call same, so puting this functions to class structure. However, How to use instance object's function method pointers about method pointers of its own? because I think the function method pointers of instance object for itself is same, How to understand instance object function method?
below I give that gstreamer Gstpad.h code snippet as example :

```
struct _GstPad {
  GstObject         object;

  /*< public >*/
  gpointer          element_private;

  GstPadTemplate        *padtemplate;

  GstPadDirection        direction;

  /*< public >*/ /* with STREAM_LOCK */
  /* streaming rec_lock */
  GStaticRecMutex       *stream_rec_lock;
  GstTask           *task;
  /*< public >*/ /* with PREROLL_LOCK */
  GMutex            *preroll_lock;
  GCond             *preroll_cond;

  /*< public >*/ /* with LOCK */
  /* block cond, mutex is from the object */
  GCond             *block_cond;
  GstPadBlockCallback        block_callback;
  gpointer           block_data;

  /* the pad capabilities */
  GstCaps           *caps;
  GstPadGetCapsFunction     getcapsfunc;
  GstPadSetCapsFunction     setcapsfunc;
  GstPadAcceptCapsFunction   acceptcapsfunc;
  GstPadFixateCapsFunction   fixatecapsfunc;

  GstPadActivateFunction     activatefunc;
  GstPadActivateModeFunction     activatepushfunc;
  GstPadActivateModeFunction     activatepullfunc;

  /* pad link */
  GstPadLinkFunction         linkfunc;
  GstPadUnlinkFunction       unlinkfunc;
  GstPad            *peer;

  gpointer           sched_private;

  /* data transport functions */
  GstPadChainFunction        chainfunc;
  GstPadCheckGetRangeFunction    checkgetrangefunc;
  GstPadGetRangeFunction     getrangefunc;
  GstPadEventFunction        eventfunc;

  GstActivateMode        mode;

  /* generic query method */
  GstPadQueryTypeFunction    querytypefunc;
  GstPadQueryFunction        queryfunc;

  /* internal links */
#ifndef GST_DISABLE_DEPRECATED
  GstPadIntLinkFunction      intlinkfunc;
#else
#ifndef __GTK_DOC_IGNORE__
  gpointer intlinkfunc;
#endif
#endif

  GstPadBufferAllocFunction      bufferallocfunc;

  /* whether to emit signals for have-data. counts number
   * of handlers attached. */
  gint               do_buffer_signals;
  gint               do_event_signals;

  /* ABI added */
  /* iterate internal links */
  GstPadIterIntLinkFunction     iterintlinkfunc;

  /* free block_data */
  GDestroyNotify block_destroy_data;

  /*< private >*/
  union {
    struct {
      gboolean                      block_callback_called;
      GstPadPrivate                *priv;
    } ABI;
    gpointer _gst_reserved[GST_PADDING - 2];
  } abidata;
};

struct _GstPadClass {
  GstObjectClass    parent_class;

  /* signal callbacks */
  void      (*linked)       (GstPad *pad, GstPad *peer);
  void      (*unlinked)     (GstPad *pad, GstPad *peer);
  void      (*request_link)     (GstPad *pad);
  gboolean  (*have_data)        (GstPad *pad, GstMiniObject *data);

  /*< private >*/
  gpointer _gst_reserved[GST_PADDING];
};
```

you can see function method pointer in instance structure and class structure from giving above code snippet. intance function method pointers are initialized by gst_pad_init function, as below:

```
static void
gst_pad_init (GstPad * pad)
{
  ........//other no important code
  GST_PAD_CHAINFUNC (pad) = NULL;    
  GST_PAD_LINKFUNC (pad) = NULL;    
  GST_PAD_CAPS (pad) = NULL;
  GST_PAD_GETCAPSFUNC (pad) = NULL;  
  GST_PAD_ACTIVATEFUNC (pad) = gst_pad_activate_default;
  GST_PAD_EVENTFUNC (pad) = gst_pad_event_default;
  GST_PAD_QUERYTYPEFUNC (pad) = gst_pad_get_query_types_default;
  GST_PAD_QUERYFUNC (pad) = gst_pad_query_default;
#ifndef GST_REMOVE_DEPRECATED
  GST_PAD_INTLINKFUNC (pad) = gst_pad_get_internal_links_default;
#endif
  GST_PAD_ITERINTLINKFUNC (pad) = gst_pad_iterate_internal_links_default;

  GST_PAD_ACCEPTCAPSFUNC (pad) = gst_pad_acceptcaps_default;

 ............//other no important code
}
```

so I confuse this issue,why there are function method pointers in intance structure rather than puting into class class structure?

Answer (score 2):

Method-function pointers belong in the class structure. This is true for any virtual method (one that can be overridden in inheriting classes).

Declaring a function pointer in the *instance* structure would imply the corresponding method is defined only on objects of this specific class and cannot be overridden (is non-virtual).

However, in this case there is no need to expose a function pointer at all, since there can never be multiple implementations of the method and thus never any ambiguity about which implementation to invoke. Following GObject conventions, you would simply declare in the header file a function that corresponds to the method and then provide an implementation in the source file.

The GObject reference manual [illustrates these scenarios](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-methods.html), with [the "Non-virtual public methods" section](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-methods.html#non-virtual-public-methods) showing what is normally done instead of declaring a function pointer in the instance structure.

---

The GStreamer code you pasted shows one exception to the above. In that code, the function pointers stored in the instance structure are effectively *properties* of a GstPad object, not methods defined on the object itself. [The description of the class](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#GstPad.description) states

> A GstElement creating a pad will typically use the various gst_pad_set_*_function() calls to register callbacks for events, queries or dataflow on the pads.

So the `activatefunc` member stores a pointer to a callback function that is invoked when the pad is activated, for instance, and similarly for the remaining function pointers. This makes sense, as a callback function is more something the object *has* than it is a part of the object's own nature.

That said, it's true a more purely object-oriented implementation might either

- Implement the callback methods directly in the class itself, expecting them to be overridden in a subclass unique to each application; or
- Implement callbacks by invoking methods on an application-supplied object that implements a specific callback [interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

My guess is the GStreamer designers chose the simpler implementation they did out of a desire to

- Allow GStreamer to be used with existing C code that may not itself use the GObject framework, and
- Keep latency low (critical in multimedia applications) by minimizing the number of chained function calls required to invoke a callback routine.

Comment: recently，I learn gstreamer,I find out that many function pointers put into instance object structure and some put into class structure in gstreamer.I don't  entirely understand this case, I realize that one difference that  the function method pointers are mostly inherited by subclass  in parent class structure  and they aren't inherited by subinstance in parent instance structure.

Comment: but I feel that for instance virtual method the subinstance structure also could overriden in parent instance structure, for example, I use subinstance initializer function to assignment new function pointer to parent instance structure 's method pointer,I think this way also can implementate inheriting of parent virtual method. but it isn't only conventionally advise in GObject  that function method pointers are overridden in inheriting instance. do I not know that if I understand this correctly ?

Comment: I'm not sure myself. I've yet to see a GObject class with a function pointer in its instance structure. I'm not sure what the purpose of that would be. Do you have an example of a GStreamer class like this you can point me to?

Comment: please see my modify this subject to add gstreamer GstPad.h code snippet again. thank you, thank you in advance,if you have any idea, please tell me.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Briefly, these function pointers are used to register callback routines and are properties of the object, not methods defined by the object's class.

Comment: @zhang007z, have I answered your question?